# How to open a file with a double click rather than JFileChooser

Tags: java

I created a mp3 player in java and then created it as a .exe file. Now to play song in mp3 player I have to choose song in `JFileChooser` then it plays that song.

```
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    Path=chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().replace('\\','/');
```

But I want that when I double click on that song in Windows explorer or in My Computer it will play that song directly like VLC or other player do. We don't need to first choose the song in a file chooser, we just need to click on a song and it play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to  Raymond Holguin's answer in your main method save the first parameter and if its a File that exists then send it to your player class and set to start playing (not show UI with play button)

```
 public static void main(String args){
     if(args.length > 0){
          java.io.File possibleAudioClipFile = new File(args[0]);
          if(possibleAudioClipFile.exists() && possibleAudioClipFile.isFile.isFile() && possibleAudioClipFile.canRead()){

 /might want to check extn or first few bytes then play or show error msg and exit/ show default UI
     }

 }
```

- besides you need to make sure each customer/user has your app assocaited with the audio file types by extention name . Can use a script in command propmt using assoc http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323526 or in windows explorer Tools/Options menu.

Answer (score 1):

This is a windows config issue, and possibly an application issue.

1) In windows you need to make the association with .mp3 files that says whenever an MP3 is opened to use your program.  If you right click on an MP3 -> Open With you can choose the defalut program for that file type

2) In your program you need to handle the file information that is going to be passed into your application in order to open it.  So instead of using File info from JChooseer your going to use the File info that is passed as an input into your application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate your application with the filetypes you support. On Windows, this means creating an association to a URI scheme in the registry. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This is what happens when you right-click and choose what executable to open a particular file type with.